# SDK 2.0 after the 1st october

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have some apps using the PHP SDK 2.x. Regarding the Roadmap Migrations planned for the 1st october, I want to know if I have to migrate all my apps to 3.x? Does they will still work on SDK v2.x after the 1st october?
Cheers!

Comment: This question is better suited to the [Facebook Developers group](http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/) as it does not concern a specific programming or implementation question that can be answered by the Stack Overflow community.

Answer (score 0):

From one of Facebook's announcements:

> By October 1, 2011, we require that all website and canvas apps must exclusively support OAuth 2.0 (draft 20). All canvas apps must use the signed_request parameter. This also implies that old, previous versions of our SDKs will stop working, including the old JavaScript SDK.

So, no they won't work, at least if you use any of the features that have changed.

Comment: The problem is I don't know if the v2.x is affected by the OAuth 2.0  migration.